# Finding a vector in $\mathbb{R}^2$ given its coordinates with respect to a given basis

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> Consider the basis $B$ of $\mathbb{R}^2$ consisting of vectors $\begin{bmatrix}3 \\ -5 \end{bmatrix}$ and $\begin{bmatrix} 2 \\ -5 \end{bmatrix}$. Find $x$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ whose vector relative to the basis $B$ is $[x]_B = \begin{bmatrix} 4 \\ 3 \end{bmatrix}$.

My answer was $x = \begin{bmatrix}18 \\ -35 \end{bmatrix}$.

*What I was thinking:*

I was thinking that $[B][x] = [x]_B$, and I solved for $[x]$ by multiplying by $[B]^{-1}$. I was thinking that, because I am looking for $[x]$, I must find some vectors such that $[B][x] = [x]_B$, as $[x]_B$ is already in the coordinate system of $B$.

*What actually worked:*

This *really* surprised me! $[B][x]_B = [x]$! It's simply matrix multiplication, and only a $2 \times 2$ and a $2 \times 1$, so it is very simple! A classmate gave me that formula, but I have no explanation as to *why* that works. I can't imagine any reason it would work, as well as why my thought did *not* work. I assume that I must be misunderstanding something, probably the notation, maybe I misunderstand what $[x]_B$ means?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are given the basis $\beta=\{v_1,v_2\}$ of $\Bbb R^2$ where
\begin{align*}
v_1 &= \begin{bmatrix}3\\-5\end{bmatrix} &
v_2 &= \begin{bmatrix}2\\-5\end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}
We wish to find $x\in\Bbb R^2$ such that
$$
[x]_\beta=\begin{bmatrix}4\\3\end{bmatrix}
$$
This is equivalent to saying that
$$
x=4\,v_1+3\,v_2=4\begin{bmatrix}3\\-5\end{bmatrix}+3\begin{bmatrix}2\\-5\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}18\\ -35\end{bmatrix}
$$

Comment: I think I understand now. $[x]_B$ means it is in the coordinates of that basis, and by multiplying [B][x] together, you get x in standard coordinates.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer!